# USB dongle that will send keystrokes as soon as it is installed

Tags: windows, arduino, usb, hid, teensy

I'm looking for a device to use at work when logging into windows systems. I configure systems for a living and the majority of these need a password to log into and all of them use long or complex password that are just a pain to type in especially when you have to do it on 25+ systems at a time.

I am basically looking for a programmable HID that will automatically type in a selected password when the device is inserted.

I found the following page which looks like exactly what I want but I don't have any experience with teensy or arduinos. So I was hoping someone might be able to show me a better or more detailed schematic to make the device with the features I would need, I don't think I need the photoresistor and 10kΩ resistor but I would like to add a push button. The code part seems to be detailed well so I'm sure I can figure out how to adapt it to what I want but any help would be appreciated.

http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/programmable-hid-usb-keystroke-dongle#Links

I would like to make the device so that as soon as it is inserted and installed it sends a password followed by the enter key. The passwords would be selected based on which switch is on. I would also like to put a push button on it that would resend the password incase the password box wasn't selected when the device was inserted.

Comment: Why not make that link clickable?

Comment: Since you are only asking about the circuit diagram, this should be moved to http://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @david Thanks for the tips. Sorry about the link This is my first time using this site also chrome extensions make it hard to see what other people will see. didn't know there was a specific site for electronics. Is there a way to move my post? or should I just delete this one and make a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little project that I'm working on which does pretty much what you're after. It's open source so you can morph it to whatever you want:

[PUB! Programmable USB Button (SourceForge project)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pub-usb/)

The key differentiator with this project is that you don't need any host drivers (*or* custom code) to program it. All you need is a text editor like Notepad (on Windows) or gedit (on Linux). All the programming is done using the rotary encoder knob.

[image: PUB! prototype image]

Comment: Thanks for the link. This looks really cool. I actually figured out the teensy and arduino one that can have over 500 pre-programmed programs with a 10 position DIP switch. The only issue I have with it is that windows can take a while on some systems before it will actually do anything so I mainly just use it for BIOs changes now.

Answer (score 1):

Too old, but I've also worked on a very similar project for an Arduino. Here is the GitHub repository:

https://github.com/AmirrezaNasiri/usb-keystroke-injector

Though it supports both SD card and Bluetooth modes, you can choose to use SD card mode only. It also supports up to 8 payloads (passwords in your case) to be typed from the SD card which can be easily extended to whatever you want.

[image]